# Adding line breaks for PSQL commands

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, psql

How can I do line breaks properly in bash script? The following command works fine without adding line breaks:

```
for i in {table1,table2,table3}; do psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "DB"."$i") TO "$i".csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"; done
```

However, I would like add to more table names in the script. I keep getting (Filename too long) error. I would like to do something like the following:

```
    for i in {table1, \
     table2, \
     table3}; do psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "DB"."$i") TO "$i".csv 
     DELIMITER ',' CSV"; done
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "}"
```

Comment: Remove the `{`, `}`, and `,`s between braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need curly braces `{}` to denote an array in bash, just do it like:

```sh
for i in table1 \
     table2 \
     table3; do psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "DB"."$i") TO "$i".csv 
     DELIMITER ',' CSV"; done
```